# Как вычислить факториал?

Tags: pascal

> Вычислить факториал заданного числа n (n> 0) () - тоесть произведение чисел от 1 до n.

Вот подобное, но у меня не выходит...

```
Program my;
var 
    i, s: integer; 
    f: longint;
begin
s := 1;
for i := 1 to 20 do
    f := f*i;
    writeln('произведение от 1 до 20 ',f);
    readln;
end.
```

Comment: Ответы дали и правильные, хорошие, но при одном условии -- считать не 20!, а поменьше. 20! в longint не полезет. Если можно -- снижайте исходные данные, если нет -- надо править программу.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что вы, как я понимаю, первоначально хотели, чтобы значение факториала содержалось в переменной "s", но позже зачем-то завели переменную "f", которая вообще хранит в себе адрес ячейки памяти, в которой находится (Вы же её не обнулили). Вот функция, возвращающая факториал до "n":

```
function factorial(n):integer;
var 
    i,f: integer; 
begin
f:=1;
for i := 1 to n do
    f := f*i;
    result:=f;
end;
```

Comment: да, разобрался) записано было в конспекте, видно когда писал перепутал

Answer (score 1):

Чуток осталось - присвоить начальное значение переменной f. Сейчас она не инициализирована, поэтому итоговое значение равно нулю.

```
Program my;
var 
    i: integer; 
    f: longint = 1;
begin
    for i := 1 to 10 do
        f := f*i;
    writeln('произведение от 1 до 10 ', f);
end.
```

Comment: переменная инициализирована, просто Assen присвоил не при инициализации, а перед циклом :) Можно 2мя способами. Пусть автор вопроса сам выбирает как ему удобней